# classpath javac: file not found:

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, compilation, javac

I was trying to run my first Hadoop program wordcount. However I was not able to compile map, reduce and wordcount.java. I used Ubuntu 12.04 , and installed Hadoop in /usr/bin/hadoop-1.2.1

worcount_01 has two sub directories, src and classes.

My map, reduce and wordcount.java are in ~/wordcount_01/src

So I first go the ~/wordcount_1, then I run

```
javac -classpath/usr/bin/hadoop-1.2.1/hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar:/usr/bin/hadoop-1.2.1/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar-d./classes/./src/*.java
```

it shows

```
javac: file not found: -classpath/usr/bin/hadoop-1.2.1/hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar:/usr/bin/hadoop-1.2.1/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar-d./classes/./src/*.java
```

I am pretty sure all paths are correct, but I do not know how to use classpath. 
Anyone can help me fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need a space between the `-classpath` option and its values:

```
javac -classpath /usr/bin/hadoop-1.2.1/hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar:/usr/bin/hadoop-1.2.1/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar-d./classes/./src/*.java
```

Answer (score 0):

resolved, it should be -d ./classes/ ./src/*.java  . I forgot to put space.